# Write dataframe to table

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a spark data frame to MYSQL table. I tried the following method:

```
dataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).format(JDBC).options(options);
```

options is a map of the following key-value pair:

- "url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
- "password", "pass"
- "driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
- "user","username"
- "dbtable","tableName"

table 'tableName' is not getting updated and I am not getting any error in spark console. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it by changing your map name because both method name and map name are the same. I am not sure but this might be the problem.

Secondly, I declare option parameters as separate variables and pass them into the option method.

`

```
url_name = "xxxx"
driver_name = "xxxx"
username = "x"
passwd = "123"
dataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).format(JDBC).options(url=url_name, driver = driver_name, dbtable = query, user=username, password=passwd);
```

`

The last thing, check the `.save()` method after options method because you are not saving.

Comment: Hi @FMA, thanks for responding. I had not used save in the end. Using save did the trick. no need to update the options map name.